# Weka: Evaluation UpdateMargins ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, weka, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an application that is accepting two files, test and train, and performing Logistic Regression using the following code:

`Logistic logisticRegression = new Logistic();
logisticRegression.buildClassifier(_data);
Evaluation evaluation = new Evaluation(_data);
evaluation.evaluateModel(logisticRegression, _testData);`

I get the following exception:

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
    at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.updateMargins(Evaluation.java:3734)
    at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.updateStatsForClassifier(Evaluation.java:3602)
    at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModelOnceAndRecordPrediction(Evaluation.java:1517)
    at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Evaluation.java:1480)`

The file in question has 11 attributes, and 342 records, so this error has really confused me.

- These files work as expected when using Weka through the Explorer so it must be something I'm doing wrong?
- I have tried using the same file as test and train - it was suggested by someone having a similar problem that the values in the train file had not been handled by the classifier, but this has not made a difference.
- I have made sure that there are no missing values in either file.
- If there is only one instance in the testing file, it does not generate this error.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you are not working on training dataset as you might not be supplying any. Moreover check the main loop of your algorithm there might be any logical error. I received the same error while adding my algorithm in simplekmeans.java and the culprit was the while loop.